# Post image using $.post via onclick="return..."

Tags: jquery, facebook, post

I'm trying to post an image using $.post method via onclick="return..." My codes are below.It doesn't post any image. I also try to post message too, it's work! So wondering whether anyone can help me on this?

```
//Index.php file
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<img src="1.jpg" id="imgURL">

<p id="wrap-btn">
//returning the image to post_to_wall function in main.js
<a href="#" onclick="return post_to_wall($('#imgURL').val())" id="btnpostwall">Post to     Wall</a>
</body>
```

---

```
//Main.js file
function post_to_wall(imgURL){
$.post('posttowall.php',{'imgURL': imgURL},function(data){
    //alert(data);
    $('#loaddiv').hide();
});
}
```

Comment: Can you do some basic debugging?  Set a breakpoint to see if you're event making it to the start of your `post_to_wall()` function.  Also, I assume you have a script tag for Main.js?  If the breakpoint indicates that `post_to_wall()` is actually being called, then check to make sure the HTTP request is being made.  You can do this with your browser's built-in tools, Fiddler, Wireshark, etc.  If the HTTP request is being made, then let's take a look at your PHP script.  These are some basic debugging steps you should use to trace down problems.  Otherwise, we can only guess...

Comment: i dont think you can post a image by jquery . you will need an iframe

Answer (score 0):

**Post image using jQuery is not possible**

You can send its src to php file and then retrieve that image from that src using PHP.

To send the src you can try like following:

```
function post_to_wall(imgURL){
   $.post('posttowall.php',{'imgURL': imgURL},function(data){
      //alert(data);
      $('#loaddiv').hide();
   });
}

$('a#btnpostwall').on('click', function() {
   post_to_wall($('#imgURL').attr('src'));
});
```